# Laravel eloquent orderBy two times

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query like this:

```
$foos= Foo::orderBy('order_number', 'asc')->limit(10)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Its ordering the "order_number" by asc. After one order again.

If there is same order number values in query. Example:

What I want is:

```
1-2-3-2-3-2-1-1-1-2
```

There are four "number 1", four "number 2", two "number 3"

Is there a chance to order each number by`created_at`, `desc`?

The result must be:

```
1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2-3-3
```

But 1s are ordered by `created_at` and 2 and 3 are ordered by `created_at`.

I have one solution but it's not concise: it uses 3 queries.

Edit1:

in my db

```
id = 1 / order = 1 / name = john / created_at = 2013
id = 2 / order = 2 / name = jack / created_at = 2016
id = 3 / order = 1 / name = jennifer / created_at = 2015
id = 4 / order = 2 / name = janice / created_at = 2014
```

after the query result must:
**john
jennifer
janice
jack**

**JOHN**'s order smaller than jack and janice and earlier than Jennifer. *(1st place)*

**JENNIFER**'s order smaller than smaller than jack and janice but not earlier than JOHN *(2nd place)*

**JANICE**'s order and **JACK**'s order is not smaller than others but janice's created_at earlier than jack. So jennifer *3rd place*. Jack *4th*.

There could be a to many orders of course.

Comment: It would be good if you would post the solution you have so far, at least.

Comment: I didn't write yet. But i can set all number's to seperated arrays with different queries, Then order each array. This is expensive solution. I am sure some people can do it shortest way. Thats what i am looking for.

Comment: Just include the solution with 3 queries, it will help us understand what exactly you want.

Comment: What are those numbers representing?

Comment: Answer updated. Sorry about my english. I could not express myself.

Answer (score 0):

First order by `id` and then order by `created_at`

```
OrderModel::orderBy('id')->latest()->get();
```

Comment: before the latest() i need to order by order_number. After that i must use latest() in for each ordered numbers.

Comment: Change id to order_number. That should first order by order number then created time